# How to clear mat- autocomplete when no option is selected from autocomplete dropdown

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I have successfully implemented mat-autocomplete and it is working fine if selected from auto complete drop down. I am facing issues when i have typed in some text and navigate to other fields without selecting below dropped in auto complete fields. It retains the value typed in autocomplete field.

I have used below approach to fix this issue -

1. MatAutocompleteTrigger - Below code I have used in ts file -

   ```
     @ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { static: false,read: MatAutocompleteTrigger })  trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
   .
   .
   .
   this.trigger.panelClosingActions
     .subscribe(e => {
      if (!(e && e.source)) {
      this.accountForm.get('accountId').setValue="";
      this.account.accountId = null;
      }
   })
   ```

   First of all , i am unable to keep it in any angular life cycle hook. This trigger doesn't get initialized during angular lifecycle hooks, but later while it receives any values form mat-autocomplete.So it clears value as soon I type in text in field(keeping the below autocomplete list; which doesn't look good)

   2.Used observalble on filterOptions(Obserable on my autocomplete field) - I have used below code for i t -

   ```
    this.filteredOptions = this.accountForm.get('accountId').valueChanges.pipe(
     debounceTime(250),
     distinctUntilChanged(),
     filter(searchString => typeof searchString === 'string'),
     filter(searchString => searchString.length > 0),
     switchMap(searchString => {
       return this.accountService.autoCompleteBrokerSearch(searchString);
     })
   );
   this.filteredOptions.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe((lookups: accountEntityModel[]) => {
     if (lookups.length === 0) {
       this.account.accountId = null;
       this.accountForm.get('accountId').patchValue('');
     }
     if(lookups.find(value => value.id !== this.account.id)){
       this.account.accountId = null;
       this.accountForm.get('accountId').patchValue('');
     }
   });
   ```

with Template code -

```
<mat-form-field  appearance="standard" >
<mat-label>{{ 'account.enterAccount' | translate }}</mat-label>
<input
 matInput
 formControlName="accountId"
 class="search-select"
 [matAutocomplete] = "accountAutocomplete"
#autoCompleteInput="matAutocompleteTrigger">
<mat-autocomplete #accountAutocomplete = "matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)" >

    <mat-option [value]="accountOption" *ngFor="let accountOption of filteredOptions | async" (onSelectionChange)="onEnteredAccount(accountOption)" >{{
        accountOption.description
      }}</mat-option>

</mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field>
```

I only require to clear the field if we have not selected anything from auto complete, and it should clear field values from form too.

Answer (score 2):

**Its working fine for me..**

HTML:

```
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input type="text" placeholder="start type.." #autoCompleteInput="matAutocompleteTrigger"
              matInput [matAutocomplete]="catAuto" [formControl]="selectedData" (keyup)="onChange($event)">
          <mat-autocomplete #catAuto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFnForAutoComplete"
              (optionSelected)="onSelect($event.option.value)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filterList" [title]="option" [value]="option.id">
                  {{option.name}}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>                  
     </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { static: false, read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
selectedData = new FormControl();

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trigger.panelClosingActions
      .subscribe(e => {
        this.selectedData.setValue(null);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the formControl-binding from your input and when you select an option you set that id to your form.

You are already calling such a function `(onSelectionChange)="onEnteredAccount(accountOption)"` in which you can do that.

Comment: Yes, but it will be triggered when i select any mat-autocomplete option.I want the field and its relevant id to be removed from form when user don't select any option from autocomplete drop down.